# How to pass variables between Relay Containers

Tags: react-router, relayjs, react-router-relay

I'm looking for the good syntax to pass a variable from a parent container to a child container.

Let's say I have theses routes, with a global widget list on `/` and specific widget lists on `/widgets/:WidgetListID`.

*Note: I use react-router-relay*

```js
<Route
    path='/' component={Layout}
  >
    <IndexRoute
      component={WidgetListContainer}
      queries={ViewerQueries}
    />
    <Route
      path='/widgets/:WidgetListID'
      component={WidgetListContainer}
      queries={ViewerQueries}
    />
  </Route>
```

It's the same `<WidgetList/>` component, rendered inside `<WidgetListContainer/>` inside `<Layout/>` and here is how I try to pass the `WidgetListID` variable:

*Layout.js*

```js
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       ...
        {children}
       ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*WidgetListContainer.js*

```js
class WidgetListContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
       ...
        <WidgetList 
          viewer={viewer}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(WidgetListContainer, {
  initialVariables: {
    WidgetListID: null
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: ($WidgetListID) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${WidgetList.getFragment('viewer', $WidgetListID)}
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

*WidgetList.js*

```js
class WidgetList extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {viewer.widgets.edges.map(edge =>
            <li key={edge.node.id}>{edge.node.widget.name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Relay.createContainer(WidgetList, {
  initialVariables: {
    WidgetListID: null
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
         widgets(first: 10, WidgetListID:$WidgetListID) { 
          edges { 
            node { 
              id, 
              name
            } 
          } 
        } 
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

I have no problem setting the `WidgetListID` variable directly inside the WidgetList relay container, it works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try to pass it from the WidgetListContainer relay container I have an empty data object `{__dataID__: "VXNlcjo="}`. Though, the variable is well printed in my getWidget() function. So something doesn't work at some point but I can't figure out what?

What would be the good syntax to pass the `WidgetListID` variable from the parent container to the child container?

Answer (score 1):

In the `WidgetListContainer`, change this:

```js
fragments: {
    viewer: ($WidgetListID) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${WidgetList.getFragment('viewer', $WidgetListID)}
      }
    `,
  },
```

to

```js
fragments: {
    viewer: ({WidgetListID}) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${WidgetList.getFragment('viewer', {WidgetListID})}
      }
    `,
  },
```

The first argument to the fragment builder is the Relay `variables`. So first you need to pull the `WidgetListID` variable out of the `WidgetListContainer`'s variables, and then you can pass it into `WidgetList.getFragment()`.

Note that the `$` symbol is only used inside the `Relay.QL` template string.  Inside the variables object, you refer to the variable by name, without the `$`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I'm missing something again, I now have  an error: `RelayFragmentReference: Variable 'WidgetListID' is undefined in fragment 'WidgetList'.`?

Comment: Sorry; I made a mistake in the getFragment call; you need to pass in the `route` as well.  So, it should be `WidgetList.getFragment('viewer', route, {WidgetListID})`.  I updated the answer, so hopefully it'll work this time :)

Comment: Hmm... I'm sorry, but it looks like my answer is incorrect.  It's not working as I expected after all. :(

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( Thank you for your help anyway! I'll keep trying... I'll let you know.

Comment: Just to follow up, the best I could come up with was to pass the value into the child component's props, and have the child set the variable with the value.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too, but I realized that the component was rendered two times: a first time with the variable as null and a second time with the passed variable. Finally, I just request the data in the WidgetListContainer et pass it as props to the widgetList. I told myself that if I could not pass a variable so I was going to pass the entire data. Why not?

Comment: This answer was very close. I've edited it. Can you try again, and accept it if it works @Victorien?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also struggled with this for a bit.
Change this:

```
 class WidgetListContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
       ...
        <WidgetList 
          viewer={viewer}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
 }
```

to this:

```
class WidgetListContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
       ...
       <WidgetList
          WidgetListID={this.props.relay.variables.WidgetListID}
          viewer={viewer}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

also in your WidgetList component's relay container don't forget to set initial variables to 
    initialVariables: {
         WidgetListID: null
  },
this setup will make your WidgetListID variable available for your WidgetList component's relay container.

Comment: oh, and don't forget the change in previous answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that too, but it's the same problem for me, empty data object `{__dataID__: "VXNlcjo="}`. Maybe I have a problem elsewhere? I don't understand because if I initialize the variable with any string it works. I only have this problem trying to pass the variable so I told myself that the problem was there but maybe not?